# Migration from bootstrap table to Angular5-data-table

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

Below is my table structure composed using bootstrap -

```
<table class="table table-hover">
  <thead class="thead-light">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="custom-venue" *ngFor="let venue of filteredVenues">
      <td [routerLink]="['/orders', venue.venueKey.id]">{{venue.name}}</td>
      <td>{{venue.address}}</td>
      <td>{{venue.description}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to migrate this to Angular5-data-table. Normal migration works but i am facing problems with providing routerlink on the 'Name' column values. Need assistance. Below is the migrated code. I need a fix particularly(only) for 'Name' column associated with RouterLink.

```
  <data-table
    [items]="venues",
    [itemCount]="venuesCount",
    (reload)="reloadItems($event)">
  </data-table>

  <data-table-column
    [property]="'name'"
    [header]="'Name'"
    [sortable]="true"
    [resizable]="true"
    [routerLink]="['/orders', venue.venueKey.id]">
  </data-table-column>

  <data-table-column
    [property]="'address'"
    [header]="'Address'"
    [sortable]="true"
    [resizable]="true">
  </data-table-column>

  <data-table-column
    [property]="'description'"
   [header]="'Description'"
    [sortable]="true"
    [resizable]="true">
  </data-table-column>
```